# Backtrack 5 R2 can't browse in firefox

Tags: firefox, internet, browser, backtrack

I download and install backtrack 5R2 in virtual machine at network mode NAT. Than I start run backtrack and in Wicd network manager and it says that is connected to network, also can ping google without losing packages, but for some reason I can't browse over the internet with firefox.

So the question is how to configure network of browser to successfully browse?

Comment: Backtrack does this on purpose I think.. you might want to check their FAQ, but that's a guess.

Comment: thnx for comment i searched on FAQ but those community is very poorly, ... i don't have much time for searching to answer so i delete those os ...

Comment: Backtrack is for advanced linux users anyways, it is probably better if you just stick with Windows.

Comment: I'm advanced and user in linux, and used lot of backtrack before, ... problem is that every time when they make new edition change network manager, so every time you have to explore how to connect to internet, ...

Comment: The goal of BackTrack is to be obscure and not easily detected. This means, not automatically connecting to things such as the Internet. I will turn on my VM later and look for a solution, but for now I would say consult their Help Documents, even if they are poorly docoumented.

Answer (score 0):

There is no DNS configured. Open Wicd and put an entry in Global DNS and restart the connection.